# Eshop total cost of items in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, shopping-cart

I am wondering if it is possible to display the total cost of all the items in my Wordpress Eshop like the below image.

[image]

I currently have a function that returns the total cost off all item, I just need to include the extra option costs which can be selected by a user before adding the item to the cart, here is the function I added to my `functions.php`:

```
// Return the total cost in cart
function get_myeshop_cart_itempricetotal(){
    global $blog_id;
    $total_price = 0;
    if(isset($_SESSION['eshopcart'.$blog_id])) {
        $item_array = $_SESSION['eshopcart'.$blog_id];
        foreach($item_array as $item) {
               $price = $item['qty'] * $item['price'];
               $total_price = $total_price + $price;
        }
    }
    return $total_price;
}
// Display cost
function display_my_cart_cost() {
    $cart_cost = get_myeshop_cart_itempricetotal();
    if ( $cart_cost > 0 ) print '£' . $cart_cost;
    else echo __('0','theme');
}
```

I am calling this function within my template using `<?php display_my_cart_cost();?>`.

<s>I do not know much **PHP**, is it possible to just modify the above function to return the cost of all cart items?</s>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to NOT modify the functions that come with the plugin. It might create bugs or conflicts - if not now in a future upgrade.

As shown in the function get_myeshop_cart_itemcount() - I think you can get the price of each item by looping through the items in the cart. You would just need to know the label for the column holding the price data. A blind guess is that it might be called "price".

Something like the code below -

```
function get_myeshop_cart_itempricetotal(){
    global $blog_id;
    $total_items_in_cart = 0;
        if(isset($_SESSION['eshopcart'.$blog_id])) {
            $item_array = $_SESSION['eshopcart'.$blog_id];
            foreach($item_array as $item) {
                   $price = $item['qty'] * $item['price']; //Check if column is called 'price'
                   $total_price += $price;
            }
        }
    return $total_price ;
}
```

Comment: Hey, i'm adding these functions to `functions.php` not touching the main plugin. Thanks for your answer, which is partly working. It gets the price of items and corrects for quantity's. How can I add in the cost of extra options? (I have select boxes that add to the price of an item).

Comment: There should be a column where the price information for the extra items are stored. Since the shopping cart is stored in the session, you can add some extra options to your order and then print the session variable that stores the shopping cart. The code for it would be `print_r($_SESSION['eshopcart'.$blog_id]);` This would show you the data structure of the shopping cart.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know I could do that. Should help me pull out the price of the `option` as I see it in there.